# Работа нескольких потоков с объектом в котором есть как синхронизированные методы, так и не синхронизированные

Tags: java, многопоточность

у мея есть простой класс с несколькими методами, некторые из них помечены synchronized, например:

```
    public class NowItNotThreadSafeClass {
    
        public SharedObject sharedResource;
    
        public  NowItNotThreadSafeClass(ShareObject shareResource) {
            this.sharedResource = sharedResource;
        }
      
        public synchronized void methodOne() {
            sharedResource.someStateChangingMethod();
        }
    
        public synchronized void methodOne() {
            shareResource.anotherStateChangingMethod();
        }
    
        public void notSynchronizedMethod() {}
            shareResource.andOneElseMethodChangingState();
    }
```

Я раотаю с переменной класса shareResource в синхронизированных методах, понимаю для чего это нужно при работе с объектом класса NowItNotThreadSafeClass несколькими потоками, понимаю, что в данном случае синхронизация происходит на объекте this, но не до конца понимаю сможет ли другой объект вызвать метод notSynchronizedMethod() при уже занятом мониторе экземпляра NowItNotThreadSafeClass (то есть если какой-то поток уже вошел в синхронизированный метод) и что будет если какой-то поток войдет в несинхронизированный метод notSynchronizedMethod первый, а другой в этот момент начнет входить в синхронизированный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует отметить, что код не скомпилируется, так как в классе `NowItNotThreadSafeClass` определены два метода с одинаковым именем `methodOne`, поэтому предположим, что эта ошибка исправлена.

> *сможет ли другой объект вызвать метод `notSynchronizedMethod()` при уже занятом мониторе экземпляра `NowItNotThreadSafeClass`*

Да, другой **поток** сможет спокойно вызвать несинхронизированный метод `notSynchronizedMethod` для одного и того же экземпляра класса `NowItNotThreadSafeClass`

> *что будет если какой-то поток войдет в несинхронизированный метод `notSynchronizedMethod` первый, а другой в этот момент начнет входить в синхронизированный*

Никакой синхронизации не произойдет, потоки отработают параллельно, то есть в данном случае последовательность вызовов методов экземпляра в классе `SharedObject` будет неопределена, и соответственно, состояние экземпляра этого класса также будет неопределенное.

---

Соответственно, если один и тот же экземпляр класса `SharedObject` будет использоваться совместно несколькими экземплярами класса `NowItNotThreadSafeClass`, для каждого из которых будут вызываться в разных потоках только *синхронизированные* методы `methodOne` / `methodTwo`, состояние в таком экземпляре `SharedObject` будет меняться неопределенным образом.